# Input não pega o type do arquivo

Tags: javascript, html, html5, input

Em minha aplicação eu possuo um simples input para pegar um arquivo `XLS` na maioria dos computadores funciona normalmente, porém em alguns está com problema. O navegador acaba não conseguindo pegar o `type` do arquivo e ao enviar o `content-type` do arquivo acaba indo como `Application/Octed-Stream` dando erro no servidor. Criei um simples formulário para testar e continuou com o mesmo problema nos computadores que dão problema.

```js
const clickButton = () => {
    const file = document.getElementById('file');
    console.log(file.files[0]);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
<button onclick="clickButton()">Click aqui</button>
```

Nesse que estou o arquivo inputado acaba ficando assim:

```
{
  "name": "motoristaPequeno2.xlsx",
  "lastModified": 1553863165554,
  "lastModifiedDate": "2019-03-29T12:39:25.554Z",
  "webkitRelativePath": "",
  "size": 9101,
  "type": "", // <- Type vazio aqui
  "slice": function slice() { [native code] }
}
```

Alguém já passou por isso?

Obs: Chrome Versão 75.0.3770.80 (Versão oficial) 64 bits
Windows Versão 1803 Compilação (17134.829)

Comment: Ué no meu mostrou o type.. Testado no chrome

Comment: Então, isso que é estranho. No meu computador pessoal também mostra, mas os da empresa não está mostrando.

Comment: qual o navegador usado na empresa?

Comment: Versão do Windows e Chrome são as mesmas ainda

Comment: Estou usando o Chrome

Comment: Você pode usar o attributo [accept](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp) no campo de upload para limitar o range de tipos selecionávies e verificar o tipo arquivo pela extensão dele e fazer uma validação mais precisa no backend. Veja a lista de mimes para excel [aqui](https://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.html)

Comment: @Vinicius.Silva O `accept` é apenas um facilitador para o usuário, para listar na pasta apenas os arquivos daquele tipo; bem como a extensão do arquivo não diz nada sobre o tipo dele, pois posso gerar um código em PHP e salvar como JPG, dependendo de como for utilizado o arquivo, continuará sendo um PHP (uma enorme brecha de segurança em muito site por aí).

Comment: O pior que estamos usando usando `accept=".xlsx"`, ele consegue fazer uma primeira "validação" e o arquivo é do tipo correto, mas por algum motivo o `type` não está sendo pego pelo input.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Acredito que você não tenha visto a parte em meu comentário "(...)fazer uma validação mais precisa no backend"

Comment: @Vinicius.Silva Sim, vi e concordo, mas comentei porque o foco da pergunta é resolver/entender o motivo de ficar vazio em alguns navegadores e nenhuma das ações que sugeriu contornaria isso. São excelentes dicas e só melhoram a aplicação, mas pareceu que você sugeriu como solução.

Comment: O problema aqui é querer usar o Mime fornecido pelo cliente como referência. Enquanto serve para algumas filtragens básicas, o tratamento final deve ser feito sempre no servidor. - O máximo que dá pra fazer com mime de cliente é recusar coisas absurdamente inadequadas (com um JS alertando pro upload inadequado, por exemplo), mas aceitar os tipos "genéricos" comuns é conveniente. Considere que nem todo mundo vai ter as extensões vinculadas aos Mime que você espera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conforme a [W3C](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-type), é esperado que o atributo `type` fique vazio quando o navegador for incapaz de determinar o MIME do arquivo em questão. Ou seja, estar vazio não é um problema e deverá ser tratado na sua aplicação.

A questão passa a ser sobre o motivo de alguns navegadores conseguirem determinar corretamente o MIME e outros não, possivelmente até entre mesmas versões do navegador. Acontece que, de acordo com [esta discussão no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11182968/1452488), a identificação do MIME por parte do navegador dependerá de ações no Sistema Operacional (obviamente) e particularmente quando é Windows, dependerá de configurações do usuário com base nos registros do sistema.

Se entendi corretamente, em alguns computadores pode não estar reconhecendo corretamente o MIME pois não há nesses sistemas operacionais a relação entre a extensão do arquivo e o MIME a ser considerado.

Em uma busca rápida encontrei que no Windows 10 o registro responsável por esta associação é o `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type`, mas alguém mais entendido de Windows poderá confirmar a informação e dizer como gerenciar tal registro corretamente.

Comment: Faz sentido, acho que é isso mesmo que está acontecendo. Mas a questão que fiquei agora é como deve ser tratado na aplicação. Eu editaria o `content-type` e enviaria para o back ou trataria lá essa questão?

Comment: @EduardoRibeiro Até pode fazer, mas a regra básica é "Nunca confie nos dados do seu cliente". Ou seja, no servidor, mesmo recebendo corretamente o MIME você deverá fazer a verificação.